# Converting broken byte string from unicode back to corresponding bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode

The following code retrieves an iterable object of strings in `rows` which contains a PDF byte stream. The string `row` was type of `str`. The resulting file was a PDF format and could be opened.

```
with open(fname, "wb") as fd:
    for row in rows:
        fd.write(row)
```

Due to a new C-Library and changes in the Python implementation the `str` changes to `unicode`. And the corresponding content changed as well so my PDF file is broken.

Starting bytes of first `row` object:

```
old row[0]: 25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 33  0D 0A 25 E2    E3    CF    D3    0D 0A ...
new row[0]: 25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 33  0D 0A 25 C3 A2 C3 A3 C3 8F C3 93 0D 0A ...
```

I adjust the corresponding byte positions here so it looks like a unicode problem.

I think this is a good start but I still have a `unicode` string as input...

```
>>> "\xc3\xa2".decode('utf8')  # but as input I have u"\xc3\xa2"
u'\xe2'
```

I already tried several calls of `encode` and `decode` so I need a more analytical way to fix this. I can't see the wood for the trees. Thank you.

Comment: What's `line`? Is that a typo for `row`? Where do the `rows` come from? Iterating over "lines" of binary data seems like an aberrant thing to do. Usually you'd just read and write a fixed-size buffer of bytes.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry, was a typo. Corrected that. Yes I know, but it's a implementation depending on an SAP library which I cannot touch... it's a data structure which I just get like this :(

Answer (score 0):

When you find `u"\xc3\xa2"` in a Python unicode string, it often means that you have read an UTF-8 encoded file as is it was Latin1 encoded. So the best thing to do is certainly to fix the initial read.

That being said if you have to depend on broken code, the fix is still easy: you just encode the string as Latin1 and then decode it as UTF-8:

```
fixed_u_str = broken_u_str.encode('Latin1').decode('UTF-8')
```

For example:

```
u"\xc3\xa2\xc3\xa3".encode('Latin1').decode('utf8')
```

correctly gives `u"\xe2\xe3"` which displays as `âã`

Comment: This seems to be reaffirming the OP's incorrect root cause analysis rather than actually fixing the problem, if I'm reading this correctly; but of course, it's quite possible that I'm the one who is misunderstanding something.  The claim that the input is now `u"\xc3\xa2"` is consistent with this answer but at odds with the old vs new dump IMHO, and I'm betting the latter is actually correct.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you should be doing

```
fd.write(row.encode('utf-8'))
```

assuming the type of `row` is now `unicode` (this is my understanding of how you presented things).